Postgres error - invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "CST"
Facing below error while running app from the cloud however this error is not getting when running from the local.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:695)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:197)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
    ... 146 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "CST"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2825)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:175)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:725)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:711)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
   

Tried with below setting as well however its still picking up the CST Timezone.
gone through multiple article as mentioned below but there is mostly the configuration discussed related to postgre only.
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/538B4F3B.5070006@aklaver.com
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/25914.1510934246%40sss.pgh.pa.us
https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/1543208
Set the serverTimezone for the jdbc connection string as below.
jdbc:postgres://localhost:3306/test?serverTimezone=UTC

Also current timezone for the postgre is UTC.
following are the commands used to show and set the timezone on postgre
SHOW TIMEZONE
SET TIMEZONE 'UTC'


set the timestamp UTC at the time of running the application on the cloud so that whenever the application JVM is trying to connect the postgre db it should use UTC as timestamp. Following commands are provided in the docker file which will used to while running application in the container.
java -Duser.timezone=UTC -jar service-docker.jar


it didn't worked for me

There is no serverTimezone parameter, so the driver is using the time zone configured for your JVM. If you don't want to change that, you can try to set the timezone parameter for the server process:
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test?options=-ctimezone=UTC


@Albe - yes its mainly due to JVM , Tried with different approch by setting timezone in the java command.

@Albe is it present for postgre?

@Albe - my bad, I mean to say serverTimezone paramater present in case of  postgre driver for jdbc connection string?

If you mean the "mysql", I just copied that from you without looking. I was talking about PostgreSQL.

@Albe - thats write, it was typo. I tried for postgre.
